# How to Create Object of Interface?

Tags: java, jooq

I have  [Field interface](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Field.html)

How to create the Object of this Interface?

Comment: [What is an interface? - The Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html)

Comment: you cannot create an object using an interface.

Comment: @WenodPathirana You can't instantiate an interface. You certainly can create an object using it (e.g., with an anonymous class).

Comment: @chrylis got the point, but you have to implement the interface to create object with anonymous class too.

Answer (score 2):

Look under All Known Implementing Classes: [CustomField](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/CustomField.html)

This is probably the class you are looking for

```
Field<T> myField = new CustomField<T>(String name, DataType<T> type);
```

For a list (array) of fields:

```
ArrayList<Field<T>> arr = new ArrayList<Field<T>>();
arr.add(myField);
```

If you're not familiar with generics, T just represents any reference type (Class) you want to use

For a simple array type (not ArrayList) it would be:

```
Field<T>[] arr = new Field<T>()[size];
arr[0] = myField;
```

Consider using an ArrayList or some other Collection, there is no reason to use a plain old array with references variables like in your case.

Comment: Yes right but i want array type

Comment: Edited the answer to include array type

Answer (score 1):

we can not `instatiate` the `interface`(do not have constructor)...

You may want to read the Java Language Specification (or your favorite Java book) on the subject of ["anonymous inner classes"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html).

Answer (score 1):

Well, there could be `Factory` class to create a instance of some `Field` interface implementations.

Anyway, API says the `Field` interface has one implementation -> `CustomField` which has protected constructor. Also it says you have to implement two methods: `void toSQL(RenderContext context)` and `void bind(BindContext context)`

```
public static class MyField<T> extends CustomField<T> {
    private final String table;
    private final String field;

    MyField(String table, String field, DataType<T> type) {
      super(table + "." + field, type);

      this.table = table;
      this.field = field;
    }

    @Override
    public void toSQL(RenderContext context) {
        context.literal(table).sql(".").literal(field);
    }

    @Override
    public void bind(BindContext context) throws DataAccessException {}
}
```

Then you can use

```
Field<Object> xxx = new MyField<Object>("table", "field",dataTypeInstance<Object>);
```

Comment: Thanks @Milan previously i have one more question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18268611/how-to-convert-tablefieldrecord-t-object-to-listsortfieldt

Answer (score 0):

You can't. An `interface` contains `unimplemented methods`, it would make no sense to make an object of that - you need to make a class `implement` the interface, and then instantiate that class.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly believe,we cannot   `instantiate`    `interface`.

You can use any implemtations of that `interface`  or  You can go for an [anonymous inner class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html)  instead.

Ex from docs

```
 btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                System.out.println("Hello World!");
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create an object of `Interface`. You can create a reference of `Interface` type and that can hold an object of any class implementing that `interface`.

so you need to have a class implementing `Field` interface, and lets assume you name it as `FieldImpl`. Then you can hold the object of FiledImpl in a reference of Field like this:

```
Field f = new FieldImpl();
```

Comment: Yes same thing i have to ask may be i asked wrong way how to do that?

Comment: @JavaProgrammer I have added more details to the answer, hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

One way or anther, you need a class implementing Field. One approach is to use an anonymous class:

```
Field myField = new Field() {
  // implementation of Field's methods.
}
```

Alternatively, you can write a named class implementing Field, and create an instance of that class.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [interface definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_%28Java%29)

> **Interfaces cannot be instantiated, but rather are implemented.**
>   A class that implements an interface must implement all of the methods described in the interface, or be an abstract class.
>   Object references in Java may be specified to be of an interface type; in which case, they must either be null, or be bound to an object that implements the interface.